# np arrays being immutable - "array is read-only"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I was trying to load `fashion_mnist` dataset form `tf.keras`. But when I try to load and edit the label, it said to be read-only. I checked and tried several Stack Overflow posts, but the problem still exist.

I was trying to load `fashion_mnist`, and the `train_labels` is immutable

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
# import tensorflow_federated as tff

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import functools
import glob
import os
import PIL
import time

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
# (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5   # Normalization
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
test_images = (test_images - 127.5) / 127.5   # Normalization

state = np.random.get_state()

# train_labels.setflags(write = 1)

# Change the order
np.random.shuffle(train_images)
np.random.set_state(state)
np.random.shuffle(train_labels)
```

This is the error:

```
ValueError: array is read-only
```

The same problem does not occur when I use mnist dataset and setflag not working as well

```
ValueError: cannot set WRITEABLE flag to True of this array
```

I have also check the flags of `train_label`

```
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
```

Comment: I assume it's the ` tf.keras...` that making labels read-only.  I suggest looking at the docs.  And yes, there are functions, even in numpy itself, that produce read only arrays.  Sometimes it's because a feature is in development, and the write behavior is not fully debugged.  But I don't use `keras` so can't shed any light on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve it by make a copy of train_labels

```
train_labels_copy = np.copy(train_labels)
```